# Bootstrap and bootbox: dynamically change the width of confirmation window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I am using Bootstrap for a web application and using bootbox (http://bootboxjs.com) for showing a window before proceeding with a delete operation.

For different delete options, I need to display different messages. I would like to show confirmation windows with different widths.

How can I do this dynamically in javascript code? I looked at everything and am unable to find 
a solution.

Thanks for any ideas and suggestions!

Cheers.

Comment: why do you accept an answer that doesn't even work? The other answer is better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible to add custom classes to bootbox windows with 'bootbox.classes'. I think you should make some standard CSS classes like small, medium, large and asign a width in CSS.

Then in every bootbox use a line like below (e.g.):

```
bootbox.classes.add('medium');
```

> According to the the documentation bootbox.classes is a helper method, so it should work. http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html

It seems to be taken out of the documentation, I have no clue if above method still works.

Below is another implementation to add your own class to a dialog (e.g.):

```
bootbox.dialog({

  message: "I am a custom dialog",
  animate: true,

  /**
   * @optional String
   * @default: null
   * an additional class to apply to the dialog wrapper
   */
  className: "medium"
  }
});
```

Comment: This is no longer in the documentation...taken out?

Comment: New version uses bootbox.setDefaults(options-object);

Answer (score 27):

None of the answers above worked for me so I fiddled around until the following did what I expected (using *Bootbox.js v4.2.0*)

**Javascript**:

```
bootbox.alert("Hello").find("div.modal-dialog").addClass("largeWidth");
```

**CSS**:

```
.largeWidth {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: You can use default bootstrap classes, like modal-sm. So your code could be: **bootbox.alert("Hello").find("div.modal-dialog").addClass("modal-sm");** less custom css lines in your code using already existant classes.

Answer (score 7):

Use jQuery .AddClass chained to the end of bootbox.confirm. My implementation looks like...

```
$("a#ArchiveBtn").click(function () {
    bootbox.confirm("Archive Location? Cannot be undone", function (result) {
        if (result) {
            $("form#ArchiveForm").submit();
        }

    }).find("div.modal-content").addClass("confirmWidth");
});
```

CSS...

```
/* BootBox Extension*/
.confirmWidth {
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just adding to previous answers on jquery'ing bootbox alert.

Consider you would like to use a one-liner rather than relying on a declaration of a css class separately. Just do, for example,

```
bootbox.alert("Customizing width and height.").find("div.modal-dialog").css({ "width": "100%", "height": "100%" });
```

Jquery's `.css()` does the trick so you can get rid of `.addClass()`.

Answer (score 4):

When setting up your box give it a seperate css class

```html
<style>
   .class-with-width { width: 150px !important; }
</style>
<script>
bootbox.dialog("I am a custom dialog", [{
    "label" : "Success!",
    "class" : "class-with-width",
    "callback": function() {
        Example.show("great success");
    }
}]);
<script>
```

Comment: Michael, thanks for chimiing in. I am using bootbox.confirm(). According to the API page (http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html), it does not allow the configuration you gave. Did I miss something? This is just a comment: defining a class for each box is really not a good solution.

Comment: I was looking at the examples page under custom dialog. http://bootboxjs.com/index.html#examples For suggesting to use a class for each width was because that was the only way the documentation showed setting any formatting properties.

Comment: why do you accept an answer that doesn't even work? The other answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `size` property. It adds the relevant Bootstrap modal size class to the dialog wrapper. Valid values are 'large' and 'small'

```
bootbox.setDefaults({ size: 'small' });
```

Or you can use the `className` property. It's an additional class to apply to the dialog wrapper.

```
bootbox.setDefaults({ className: 'w-100' });
```

**Css**

```
// Example class (a bootstrap v4 utility class)
.w-100 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I use `setDefaults` in these examples but these properties can be used on any bootbox dialog, you will override the defaults this way.

```
bootbox.alert({ message: 'But without me how can you have mass?', className: 'w-100' })
```

To preserve the defaults you can chain a jQuery call or even access the actual DOM ;).

```
bootbox.alert('Whoops!').addClass('w-100');
bootbox.alert('Sorry!')[0].classList.add('w-100');
```

> `bootbox.classes` isn't supported in versions > `4.4.0`

Answer (score 1):

To resize the whole dialog, please, use "div.modal-dialog" instead of "div.modal-content":

```
.find("div.modal-dialog").addClass("confirmWidth");
```

The css used is simply e.g.:

```
.confirmWidth {
  width:350px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this- `size:"small"` or `size:"large"`

Comment: Or 'extra-large'!